# Can I boot a laptop to USB with Windows with no hard drive?

Tags: windows, bootable-media

I'm on a long trip with little access to hardware support or supplies. I'm working on one laptop and my wife is working on the other. The hard drive on her laptop has just died (according to the BIOS self test). I have my working laptop, an external hard drive, USB thumb drive, and various other tools.

My wife MUST have a working machine, although only for doing basic word processing on a single document. That's all. She can't really use my machine because I need to be using it, although I can use mine to try to get her functional again.

Is there any way to make a bootable copy of Windows that could run *completely off a USB stick*, and boot just enough for her to use the machine as a word processor?  I have an old copy of the MS Word installer, or we could try LibreOffice, or maybe even Google Docs, if we can get only a browser window working.

Really, anything to boot this machine without a working hard drive, just enough to do the most basic stuff, until we can get back to a place to service this machine and/or get another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and by far the fastest is to put [Ubuntu on a USB flash drive](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) and boot from that. By default, LibreOffice, Firefox browser and Thunderbird email applications are all included with the Ubuntu Linux OS in less than 8 GB. Most users would have no trouble using Linux, if used to MS Windows.

You can even have the flash drive retain work by adding a partition for [persistent storage,](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) but use a fast USB drive for that option, or response slows.

**N.B.** To use any USB boot device, you'll need to access BIOS/UEFI. That should not pose a problem on you own machine, but would be problematical elsewhere.

Comment: This worked perfectly, really almost miraculously, because after creating the boot drive, not only did it work (and I have virtually no Linux experience), but it succeeded in installing Ubuntu on the hard drive that the machine itself said was dead. A Window bootable drive that I tried was not able to accomplish this, but I wish I knew why.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank, why Windows failed to install *might* be due to its size or due to remnants of a previous installation. Glad Ubuntu fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Freeware for that: WintoUSB
https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html

For Win10 64bit you need 32GB Stick or Drive USB3 is recommend

Here you find the Guide, u need a USB Device an Iso with the Windowssetup
https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en-US/How-to-use-WinToUSB-ISO-To-USB.html

That helps me sometimes ago.